# Do I need to use NatSpec annotation to describe functions in interfaces?

Tags: solidity, natspec

I am using VS Code with Solidity [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity). While adding NatSpec annotation I mentioned that NatSpec tags isn't highlighted in interfaces.
For example I have my NatSpec description of function in the contract and in the interface:

[image]

[image]

Do I need to copy description from contract to interface?